# Is there a way to fix the height of tableOutPut or dataTableOutput in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

The app pasted below has a problem; when you hover over some of the data points, the size of the table output increases vertically, pushing the plot down and deselecting the points.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

#example text with short and long entries
example_text <- c("short",
                  "This text is fairly long and it changes the size of the table: maybe there is a scrolling option?",
                  "also short",
                  "Here we have another example of long text ruining everything; I would maybe accept it expanding downwards or sideways",
                  "not long",
                  "I'm at a loss for what to do so I'm asking stackoverflow, a website that has helped millions of stuck people")

example_data <- tibble(x = (1:6) ^2, y = sqrt(1:6), hover_text = example_text)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(10,h1( "hover over the points and the changing size of the table moves the plot and deselects points")),
        column(2,tableOutput("dynamic_table"))
    ),
    fluidRow(
        plotOutput("plot_out",hover = "plot_hover"),
    )
    
    
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
    output$plot_out <- renderPlot(ggplot(example_data,aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(size = 5) + labs()) 
    
    table_out <- reactive(nearPoints(df = example_data,
                                     coordinfo = input$plot_hover,
                                     maxpoints = 1,
                                     threshold = 100))
    
    output$dynamic_table <- renderTable(table_out())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I forced this behavior here by giving column width 2 to force the table to resize vertically, but in my real use case table itself is quite wide and resizes vertically even with the column width is 12.

So I am looking for something to permanently set the vertical size of the data table regardless of what text is displayed.  It could be a tabular output from a different package that uses a scrollbar instead of resizing.  It could be an alternative to `fluidRow` that doesn't dynamically change size.  A hacky alternative would be to add a column with a taller element so that will generally be taller than the table, but I haven't tried that/don't know if it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to add fix the height of your `fluidRow` with enough space for the table to be rendered you can do this by adding a `style` argument to your fluid row and giving enough space

```
fluidRow(id="tablerow",style="height:400px;",
        column(10,h1( "hover over the points and the changing size of the table moves the plot and deselects points")),
        column(2,tableOutput("dynamic_table"))
    )
```

Another solution would be to add an overflow to the `tableOutput` css and fix the height of your `fluidRow` if you wish to keep the height of your fluid row narrow, in this example I use 200px

example code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

#example text with short and long entries
example_text <- c("short",
                  "This text is fairly long and it changes the size of the table: maybe there is a scrolling option?",
                  "also short",
                  "Here we have another example of long text ruining everything; I would maybe accept it expanding downwards or sideways",
                  "not long",
                  "I'm at a loss for what to do so I'm asking stackoverflow, a website that has helped millions of stuck people")

example_data <- tibble(x = (1:6) ^2, y = sqrt(1:6), hover_text = example_text)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        # Note the wrapping of the string in HTML()
        tags$style(HTML("
                        
                        
                        #dynamic_table{
                        
                        overflow-y:auto;
                        height:200px;
                        }
                        
                        "))
    ),
    
    
    fluidRow(id="tablerow",style="height:200px;",
        column(10,h1( "hover over the points and the changing size of the table moves the plot and deselects points")),
        column(2,tableOutput("dynamic_table"))
    ),
    fluidRow(
        plotOutput("plot_out",hover = "plot_hover"),
    )
    
    
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
    output$plot_out <- renderPlot(ggplot(example_data,aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(size = 5) + labs()) 
    
    table_out <- reactive(nearPoints(df = example_data,
                                     coordinfo = input$plot_hover,
                                     maxpoints = 1,
                                     threshold = 100))
    
    output$dynamic_table <- renderTable(table_out())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```